# jQuery .html(): Missing elements from beginning of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm selecting a `<div>`, like so:

```
var html = $('div#mydiv').html();
```

Both *in console*, and in the DOM when I paste the `html` var back in, there are two elements missing from the beginning of the div, which is structured like so:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label for="input"></label>
    <div class="notes"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

I'm only getting from the 'notes' div on down - NOT the input or label.  It's the weirdest thing.  Any ideas?

EDIT: By 'ideas', I mean - yes, I know this should work just fine.  I'm wondering what bugs could be causing the weirdness.  There is some PHP laced into the input and label - but those output just fine in the div where they originate, but do NOT show up in the console or in the div where I'm setting the html via jQuery.  I'm looking to see if there's malformed HTML, but I don't think so.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle, can't see why this won't work.

Comment: +1, @elclanrs. [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Comment: What you have works already. You have something else going on that you haven't shown us: http://jsfiddle.net/er4Uq/

Comment: Those elements exist on page load? Do you have more than on element on on the page with the same ID? Any malformed HTML markup?

Comment: Working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/MQVK8/

Comment: Expanded my post based on this feedback.

Comment: As everybody else said, should work. When are you calling your code? Is it after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it after $(document).ready() in a callback.